# FT232 Custom Display Name and Device Description

Tags: embedded, usb-device, ftdi

I have put a FTDI FT232RL onto a PCB to control a Microcontroller via USB. It's working fine. When I connect the board to my Windows 10 PC, the FT232RL is recognized as `USB Serial Port (COMx)`.

I want to customize this name. I downloaded the FTDI FT_Prog utility, in which I could change the Product Description, Manufacturer etc. I successfully wrote the changes to the EEPROM according to FT_Prog.

[This website](http://www.alauda.ro/2013/11/changing-ftdi-descriptors/) described the exact procedure to follow, which I did, but in the Device Manager the name does not change (nor after reboot). I also checked the device name on a Ubuntu 18.04 device by running `ltusb`, but my custom name is not showed there either.

Can someone tell me if it is even possible to change this name on the chip side, without changing any local drivers? And if it is possible, how to do it?

Comment: take a look at ft_prog utility provided by FTDI... if it can be done,  that's how

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, but your comment is already covered in my question.

Answer (score 2):

The OS selects a driver based on the VID and PID that it reads from the device, and it is the driver that determines what is displayed in the user interface.

In order to change it, you would need both a different PID and a modified driver. Probably not worth the effort.

Comment: So can you confirm that the FTDI serial driver will always display *USB Serial Port (COMx)* and ignore the product description?

Comment: @Codo: No, I can't confirm that. I'm just saying how it works in general.

Comment: ftdi chips have some eeprom in them that you can configure over USB, e.g. "in the factory"

Comment: @vicatcu: Yes, we know that. That isn't what the question is about.

Comment: I checked the Devices and Printers inside the Windows Control Panel. Over there, the name I put into the EEPROM is properly displayed. Just not in the Device Manager.

Comment: In that case, you just need a different Device Manager!